# How to use lookahead and lookbehind in vim in the same line

Tags: regular-expression

I am trying to delete all the spaces that aren't sandwiched by a letter. So this

```
 I am trying; but ; I can't find a way    ;
```

should be this

```
I am trying;but;I can't find a way;
```

I tried this but it doesn't work.

```
:%s/\([A-Za-z]\)\@<! *\([A-Za-z]\)\@!//g
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"Aren't sandwiched by a letter" means *does not have: a letter before it and a letter after it*, when expressed through [De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws): *does not have a letter before it **OR** does not have a letter after it*. What your regular expression is matching is *does not have a letter before it **AND** does not have a letter after it*; so it would only match between something like `# ; $` (which your example does not have). Maybe it becomes clearer when we condense the collection to [`/\a`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/pattern.txt.html#%2F%5Ca) and remove the superfluous grouping:

```
/\a\@<! \+\a\@!/
```

I've also changed `*` to `\+`; though matching *no* sandwiched spaces and replacing them with *nothing* doesn't do harm, it's imprecise (and may be a bit more inefficient).

To arrive at the correct pattern, we need to turn the AND to OR, by introducing a branch with `\|` ([`:help /\bar`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/pattern.txt.html#%2F%5Cbar)):

```
/\a\@<! \+\| \+\a\@!/
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation. What if some of the letters are accented characters like Š or é? What should I use instead of \a?

Comment: That's unfortunately still a weak spot in Vim; all built-in classes and sets do not contain them; you have to include them yourself; see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19385458/vim-regex-matches-unicode-characters-are-as-non-word

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of `\zs` and `\ze`.

```
:s/\v^\s+|\s+$|[^[:alpha:][:space:]]\zs\s+|\s+\ze[^[:alpha:][:space:]]//g
```

`:s/\v<pat1>|<pat2>|<pat3>|<pat4>//g` --- delete all matches using "very magic" mode

`^\s+` --- leading spaces

`\s+$` --- trailing spaces

`[^[:alpha:][:space:]]\zs\s+` --- matches anything except alpha or space followed by space(s), but selects space(s) only

`\s+\ze[^[:alpha:][:space:]]` --- matches space(s) followed by anything except alpha or space, but selects space(s) only